# Number of words- Adjacent letters unequal

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many words of length $6$ are there when adjacent letters being equal is not allowed?

My try:
We have $26$ choices for the first position and $25$ for the remaining $5$ positions because if we choose any alphabet for the first position we have $25$ left for second and for the third we still have $25$ ($-1$ for the letter which is in $2$nd position) and so on.

So, is $26 \cdot 25^{5}$ the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some additional information affirming your answer.

> The words with no consecutive equal letters are so-called *Smirnov words*. If you are curious about them you might have a look at example III.24 in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* which explains some properties of them.

We count the number of Smirnov words of length $n$ with the help of *[formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series)*. The coefficients of $z^n$ give the number of words of length $n$.

> It turns out that the *power series* of Smirnov words with $26$ letters is
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{26z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}&=\frac{1+z}{1-25z}\\
> &=1+26z+650z^2+16250z^3\\
> &\qquad+406250z^4+10156250z^5+253906250z^6+\cdots
> \end{align*}

The coefficients of $z^n$ were calculated with the help of Wolfram Alfa.

> We observe, the number of Smirnov words of length $6$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> 253906250=2\cdot5^{10}\cdot13=26\cdot25^5
> \end{align*}

Comment: That's the reason I love Mathematics. An explanation for everything.
Thank you so much.

Comment: @max: You're welcome! I see, there are many good reasons to love mathematics. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the answer will be $$ 26 * 25^5 $$ and your method is absolutely correct.